# Get form collection value using mvc paging

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How can get form collection value while paging? When i submit form then i can get form collection value. when click next page then i can not get form collection value. so what we need to change in pager?

Kindly suggest me

```
public ActionResult index(FormCollection fc, int? page)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Please , page id make a first and must be pass default=0



   public ActionResult index( int page, FormCollection fc)
    {

    }
```

Comment: I used this way but  I cant get form collection value

Comment: This error is stuck my work. Please add more suggestion

Comment: can you share with mode code for better under standing

Comment: Main theme is maintain checkbox  selected value  while mvc paging. The check used filter.When i click open checkbox means it show the related open records.